# Adding multiple Loopback Alsa devices in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, alsa

I need to create virtual loopback alsa sinks in my ubuntu setup. I can create one by adding the following to /etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf

```
alias snd-card-0 snd-aloop
options snd-aloop index=21 pcm_substreams=8
```

I need to create multiple of these but I can't seem to find documentation on how to distinguish between the virtual cards. I would like to create 20.

Comment: This question have better chances of being answered in [askUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This creates five loopback cards:

```
options snd-aloop enable=1,1,1,1,1 index=10,11,12,13,14
```

Comment: for those like me confused about the lack of an 'options' command, you need to write this line in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf